# Why is \IF throwing an error?

Tags: beamer, line-numbering, algorithmic

I am writing algorithm but it is giving error. Please see the code given below:

```
\documentclass{beamer} 
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithmic}
\STATE $S \Leftarrow (u,1);$
\WHILE{$S \neq \phi $}
\STATE $(u,1) \Leftarrow S ;$
\STATE color[$u$] := gray;
\IF{$k \le $ deg$(u)$};
\STATE $S \Leftarrow (u,k+1);$
\ELSE[$N$ ]
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

> Question : How to give numbering to each line?

Comment: Can you please make the example into a full (minimal) compilable document?

Comment: You're missing `\ENDIF` and at least a `\STATE` between `\ELSE` and `\ENDIF`.

Comment: Since you have some responses below that seem to answer your question, please consider marking one of them as ‘Accepted’ by clicking on the tickmark below their vote count (see [How do you accept an answer?](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1852)). This shows which answer helped you most, and it assigns reputation points to the author of the answer (and to you!). It's part of [this site's idea to identify good questions and answers through upvotes and acceptance of answers](http://tex.stackexchange.com/about).

Answer (score 5):

You asked,

> How to give numbering to each line?

Since you're using the `algorithmic` environment, simply change `\begin{algorithmic}` to `\begin{algorithmic}[1]` if you want every single line numbered. Use `\begin{algorithmic}[2]` if only every second line should be numbered, `\begin{algorithmic}[5]` if only every fifth line should be numbered, etc.

You also have (at least) three syntax errors in the algorithmic code block: (a) a missing `\ENDIF` statement, (b) missing instruction(s) under the `\ELSE` branch, and (c) a spurious `;` symbol immediately after `\IF{...}`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{algorithm,algorithmic}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\begin{algorithmic}[2] % number every 2nd line
\STATE $S \Leftarrow (u,1);$
\WHILE{$S \neq \phi $}
  \STATE $(u,1) \Leftarrow S ;$
  \STATE color[$u$] := gray;
  \IF{$k \le $ deg$(u)$}
    \STATE $S \Leftarrow (u,k+1);$
  \ELSE[$N$]
    \STATE something;
  \ENDIF
\ENDWHILE
\end{algorithmic}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```